# Wierd linkage behavior - gcc libraries

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors

I have two libraries libA, libB and an application 'app'.
libB uses functions from libA, and 'app' uses symbols from both libraries.
I added two new functions - 'print_data' and 'print_data_char' to libA which I call only in libB, and now getting:

```
undefined reference to 'print_data'
undefined reference to 'print_data_char'
```

Here is the actual command

```
arceb-linux-gcc apps/applications/dpi/dpi_app/build/Obj_linux_arc_sim/src/main.o apps/applications/dpi/dpi_app/build/Obj_linux_arc_sim/src/utl.o ./dpe/dp/lib/ezdp_linux_arc_sim.a ./dpe/sft/lib/sft_linux_arc_sim.a ./dpe/dpi/lib/dpi_linux_arc_sim.a  -O2 -o apps/applications/dpi/dpi_app/bin/ezdpi_app_linux_arc_sim
```

libA = sft_linux_arc_sim.a

libB = dpi_linux_arc_sim.a

I checked libA with nm:

```
ezpacket_internal.o:
00000001 a __ARCCOMPACT__
         U __udivsi3
         U fprintf
         U fputc
         U fputs
         U fwrite
0000001c T print_data
00000000 T print_data_char
```

Also there are other symbols in libA which libB does recognize. It seems that only the two new symbols are missing.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-lA -lB -lA -lB`, you mean? :)

Comment: @Elad Weiss can you post the `gcc` command you execute to build your software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghosh's answer: **-lA -lB -lA -lB** fixed it :)

(It took me about an hour to understand that it's not a typo)

Apparantly there is importance to the lib order when linking. See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

In fact I believe even **-lB -lA** would solve it :)

Thanks!